# Как сделать Паузу и продолжение в pygame

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

создаю игру на pygame и если клавиша P нажата то игра остонавливается,но мне нужно если я ещё раз нажал на клавишу P игра продолжалось

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick но зачем? суть вопроса понятна: человеку нужно реализовать паузу в игре, можно и без кода объяснить чуваку, что делать

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно сделать булевую переменную `paused` (или с похожим названием), которая будет показывать, находится ли игра на паузе или нет (True, если да, и False если нет).

Дальше нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу P переменная `paused` инвертировала своё значение (подсказка: это делается с помощью команды `paused = not paused`)

Потом в игровом цикле вам нужно написать следующее:

```
if paused:
    # Отрисовывать сообщение, показывающее что игра на паузе
else:
    # Делать всё, что делали до этого (обработка физики в игре, отрисовка и т.д.)
```

Таким образом если игра на паузе, то на окне будет выводиться сообщение по типу "Пауза. Нажмите P для продолжения" или как вы сами решите, а в обратном случае всё будет происходить как и было до этого.